# Extract a portion of an array in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have an array of type character.

For ex: `{AA,BB,CC,DD,EE,FF,GG, hh, II, jj,KK}`

From the above array i need to extract for ex: from 3rd position to 7th position which is `{CC,DD,EE,FF,GG}`

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the positions, you can simple do this:

```
SELECT myarray[3:7] FROM mytable ...;
```

Comment: +1, I'd also add that PostgreSQL have 1-based indexing, which is not very common

Comment: +1, you can use the unnest(myarray) function to have the array values in separate rows. Note that: It will duplicate the records you have.